# I can't get into my Outlook 2010. Get odd error message

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

No matter what I do I can't get into my Outlook 2010 on my laptop. Every time I try I get the same error msg:

```
Your IMAP server wants to alert you to the following:
Please log in via your web browser:
http://support.google.com/mail/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=7875
4(Failure).
```

I click on OK and get a box that says "Enter your user name and password for the following server".  `Server: imap.gmail.com`. Then it asks for my username and password, which I provide and hit "OK". But it just brings me back to the the original error message and I try doing it all over again. It won't let me copy & paste the long URL into the browser, so I type it in but always get a message that there is no such page. Can anyone help?

It just occurred to me to try and get in via my iPhone and that works, but I can't get in via my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried logging into your gmail via your web browser?

Comment: Have you tried without your antivirus suite enabled? Disable it and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Google has marked less secure application because they use insecure connections. You need to allow those application in Google settings.

Follow the steps given [here](http://www.codematrics.com/your-imap-server-wants-to-alert-you-to-the-following-please-login-via-your-web-browser-gmail/):

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue based on Microsoft's KB: [#2984937](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2984937)

The solutions proposed are either:

Enable two factor authentication (you would need to use the app-specific password then)

OR

Enable Basic Authentication for your Gmail account